# how to add a view in another view using layout inflatter

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I created mainLayout with two  buttons

add: to add other layout

remove : to remove other layout.

```
    <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
             android:textStyle="bold"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:text="Add View"
             android:onClick="addView" />

      <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
             android:textStyle="bold"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:text="Remove View"
             android:onClick="removeView" />
```

now i wrote following code to add the view
when I click on addView button

```
               LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout,null);


    mainLayout.addView(view);
```

**the view is added below the main layout**.
But I want the view to add right below addView button(and above removeView button and not in the bottom of main Layout)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a framelayout between the two buttons.

Then on runtime inflate your view into the framelayout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService (LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout,null);  
    myframeLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: it's not working
I added following

   <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Answer (score 0):

Best way to reuse layouts in Android is by using `<include>` tag.
Check here for more ways of using this: [Re-using layouts with include tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new layout that you wish to add using the `<merge>` tag like:

```
<merge ...>
   //your layout
</merge>
```

Add the `<include>` layout with visibility gone(or invisible) in your primary layout. And by handling the event that you want you can simply adjust the visibility the way you like.